# difference between reference and integer initialization on a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

With this code:

```
int a = 10;
int *ap = 4;

printf("%d", ap);
```

What is happening when I initialize the int pointer ap with 4?

Why does

```
printf("%d", ap);
```

work, but

```
printf("%d", *ap);
```

throws an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `4` is not a valid memory address(in your environment). If you try to dereference a pointer that has an invalid memory address you get an error. You should initialize it with a proper memory address

```
int a = 4;
int *ap = &a;

printf("%d", *ap);
```

or

```
int *ap = malloc(sizeof(int));
*ap = 4;

printf("%d", *ap);
free(ap);
```

Answer (score 0):

`int a = 10` sets `a` to `(int)10`, i.e. the plain old integer 10. `int *ap = 4` sets `ap` to `(int*)4`, i.e. the **memory address** 0x00000004. It is a relatively safe assumption that your process does not have permission to access address 4, hence the segmentation fault (or whatever they call it these days) when you try to do so with `*ap`.

And by the way: For portability, use `%p` to `printf` pointers. (It is not guaranteed that `sizeof(int*) == sizeof(int)`, which has the potential to cause a subtle printing bug.)